# I have a 60fps AS3 movie that loads a 15fps AS2 animation. Why does the AS3 movie slow down?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame-rate

I had a 15fps AS2-based online system which plays animations.  There are thousands of those externally loaded animations in AS2 swf format.

I upgraded the main system to use AS3 and run at 60fps, and accordingly updated it's own embedded animation keyframes to be spaced out 4x what they were so they play normally at 60fps.

Since I can't update all the thousands of individual 15-fps AS2 animations that are loaded from external sources, I have to play them back as-is.  Actually, I hack the byte stream header to force them to load as AS3.  They load and play fine, but it seems like the main movie is temporarily reducing it's frame rate to match the child movie while it plays.  That is causing it's own animations to appear very sluggish (playing at 15fps after their keyframes were updated to be viewed at 60fps).

At first I thought it was slow down from the processing of the video file, but now I realize the slower child clip seems to be causing the player to temporarily reduce it's frame rate to match.  Can anyone confirm this temporary slow down or suggest a workaround?

EDIT: The animations have sounds that are "synced to stream", and I vaguely remember reading about some exception for that that will cause the player to slow down where it normally would keep the frame rate of the parent loader.

Comment: Your guess is probably correct. Since the audio data is interleaved with the frame data, I wouldn't expect Flash to advance the playhead until a stream block for a given frame is done playing. You probably have to split up the sound stream blocks as well. If you can assume that the only codec employed is MP3 it might not be too hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Flash don't spaces frames, and you have only one container, so Flash has to match all frame rates.

The solution is a bit difficult: control frame rates with Action Script. I explain you the idea:

- You have to create a Timer and an Array, the interval of the Timer will be the loaded file frame rate. If it's 15 frames per second then the interval in seconds will be 1/15.
- You have to make a loader that loads the file, stops it and pushes it in the Array.
- Each time the timer ticks, it will loop all the Array objects and do `nextFrame` on each one, so you can have tons of files at the same frame rate, but different from main movie.

And that's it, this is the lesser CPU consuming model of an internal frame rate controller. Keep in mind that this model is for files with the same frame rate, if you modify it, you can do the same for different frame rates.

The other solution is to modify all the files in flash to have the same frame rate, with your quantity of files I think this solution is the best.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but assumed it wouldn't work since my files have audio "synced to stream".  The video makes sense to step through at any rate, but will calling "nextFrame" cause the audio to play correctly or at all?

Comment: Also not sure what you meant by "Flash don't spaces frames".  I had 15fps animations that for example had keyframes on frames 1,4,8 so to make it play back at the same rate at 60fps, I had to space them out 4x by moving them to 4, 16, and 32, since 60fps is 4x as fast as 15fps.

Comment: You might also be able to use something like the Greensock timeline manager to simulate playing a movie at a specific rate: http://www.greensock.com/timelinemax/ - it can tween any object property, including the `currentframe` of your target mc.

Comment: With 'Flash don't spaces frames" I was meaning that Flash don't spaces them automatically as you expected, of course you can do it by hand, but we are trying to avoid this isn't it? If you have audio in the frames this is a bit more complicated... Try to use Greensock as JcFx says.